# What does firefox safe mode do?

Tags: javascript, macos, html, firefox, jplayer

I am responsible for developing a html5 game in which m4v videos are loaded and played using the jplayer jquery extension. Everything was working ok until Firefox 11 Mac was released (it works in Windows).

The streams also work when FireFox Mac is started in Safe Mode.

I should also mention that the audio will stream but not the video outside of safe mode.

It isn't a problem with my plug ins, I've tried disabling them all outside of safe mode and it still wont stream.

So my question is, what can be blocking the video streaming in normal mode that is switched off when starting Firefox in safe mode?
Any suggestions?

I can't post the URL of the game, it's unreleased and I don't think my employers would be too happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe mode disables all extensions, the JS JIT and hardware acceleration of painting, and maybe a few other things.

I'd try testing disabling the JIT manually and disabling hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was the Hardware acceleration. Looks as though I was signed into my Facebook dev account when i posted the question. I'll mark it as correct when i'm next on that.

Comment: @AdamWaite Please do file a bug with steps to reproduce, especially if it's also reproducible in a Mac nightly build!

Comment: @BorisZbarsky How can I disable the JIT manually? I'm having problems as well similar to this that are not fixed by disabling hardware acceleration, but are fixed by using safe mode.

Comment: In a current Firefox release, go to about:config, and toggle the "javascript.options.baselinejit" and "javascript.options.ion" options to false.  Just don't leave it that way long-term, because it's really a _lot_ slower when executing JS...

If you discover that toggling those preferences makes your problems go away, please let me know, or file a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ directly!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Maybe you have a Plugin (not an Add-on) what causes the Problem.
Safe Mode just disables eveything from third party (and I think a little more)

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode

Look at your Add-ons and then switch to Plugins, where you then can disable other Plugins.

Comment: It's not the plug-ins. Tried disabling 1 by 1, and it appears that safe mode doesn't actually disable them since the the stream plays in safe mode.

Comment: @AdamWaite: Well you said you are using HTML5 tech. where no plugins are needed (what I know - maybe I'm wrong here).

I think some plugins are prevent streaming the m4v - or what also could be: Firefox under Mac does not support m4v.